# Problem to show the solution of the transport equation is a solution

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

Quick recall of the transport equation: I have the Cauchy problem
\begin{cases} 
      u_t(x,t)+ \langle c, \nabla_xu(x,t)\rangle=0, \text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,a) \\ u(x,t)=g(x), \text{ on } \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{cases}
The solution is then $u(x,t)=g(x-ct)$, but I'm trying to verify that by simply putting it in the main equation:
$u_t(x,t)=-g_t(x-ct)\cdot c$, which seems to be a vector to me, and since $u_k(x,t)=g_k(x,t)$ we have that $\nabla_x u(x,t)=\nabla_x g(x-ct)$ which is also a vector.

My problem is that not only can't I prove that $c \cdot g_t(x,t)+ \langle c, \nabla_xg(x,t)\rangle=0$, but also I'm adding a vector to a sclar... Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused because there is no such thing as $g_t$: $g$ is a function on $\mathbb R^n$, so

\begin{align}
u_t (x, t) &= \frac{d}{dt} g (x-ct) \\
&= \nabla_x g (x-ct) \cdot (-c)\\
&= - \nabla_x g (x-ct)\cdot c \\
&= -\nabla_x u (x, t) \cdot c. 
\end{align}